# Horizontal 'Sub Menu' Navigation

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, menu

I am building a website from a design sent over to me but am having trouble figuring out how to create a horizontal sub menu. If you view the site as it is now, you will see the ABOUT menu item has dummy child pages/links. The sub menu drops down vertically. How can I get this to be horizontal like in the attached screenshot?

Link: http://website-test-lab.com/sites/tcf

Here is the jsfiddle: jsfiddle.net/huwrowlands/2sQbn (basic code)

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `display:inline-block;` or `float:left;` on the `li` elements. Like you have on the other `ul`.

e.g:

```
.nav ul li ul li {float: left}
```

or

```
.nav ul li ul li {display:inline-block;}
```

Comment: Tried this. The problem is the children are contained by the parent width. So the sub menu won't spread out further than the width of the 'about' li.

Answer (score 0):

You need to float elements inside drop down menu.

```
.nav ul li ul li {float: left}
```

And remove width from .sub-menu

Comment: Tried this. The problem is the children are contained by the parent width. So the sub menu won't spread out further than the width of the 'about' li.